# What is the solution for iphones not supporting HTML Div background images with correct resulution?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page and I wanted to add parallax effect to it. so I created a div and set the image  as div background. That is ok the problem is iphones are not displaying this image in correct resolutions when opening web page but android devices are supporting to this.

**this is the html part**

```
<div class="banner" data-z-index="1">

        <!--contact number div-->
        <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5  col-xl-5 phonebox" id="number" data-z-index="2">
            <p  class=" phoneno">+94 71 819 2824/ +94 71 686 3475</p>
        </div>


        <h1 class="erahome faded">Welcome to Era Homes ...</h1>

        <h4 class="life faded">"Space for life"</h4>

        <h3 class="year faded">Since 2012</h4>

    </div>
```

**this is the css part**

```
.banner{
background: url('images/back.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
width:100%;
height:444px;
margin-top: -2px;
```

}

How can i get displayed this back ground image in iphones like in other devices?

Comment: <h3 class="year faded">Since 2012</h4> you start off with h3 and close it with h4 which is effectively malformed. Browsers tend to behave differently when it comes to recovering from malformed HTML and this may be the reason why it doesn't behave the same across device. Long shot but at least fix this anyway to eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem with iOS where `background-position: fixed` doesn't work.

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=background%20fixed) has it listed too.

I had a similar problem in the past and I solved it using this code which I uploaded
to my github repo: [iOS Background Hack](https://github.com/shadow-lad/iOS-Background-Hack)

Here is the working example hosted on Github Pages: [Website](https://shadow-lad.github.io/iOS-Background-Hack/)

Basically what I did was add a `div` with `position: fixed` with `top: 0` and `left: 0` occupying the whole `viewport` with the required `background-image` and added a `z-index: -1` so that it sits below all the other elements of the page and instead of the `body`, I added a `background` to alternating `sections` so that the image is visible with paralax effect in the `sections` with no `background`.